# How do I create a custom polygon with box2d for iphone framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, box2d-iphone

I would also like to know when each object is selected. is this possible with box2d? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

YES, you can do this with box2d.
But , I think, read the Box2d user manual CAREFULLY and PATIENTLY may be the best way for you.